# mysql drop down assign variables

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a function that prints a drop-down menu with values from a mysql table. I'd like the function to also assign variables associated with the value chosen from the drop-down. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM table");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
$select= '<select name="select">';  
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['name'].'</option>';
  }
}
$select.='</select>';
echo $select; ?>
```

The best scenario would be if the currently selected value is assigned to $variable, and then another query takes place for that values row within the table. Is something like this possible without reloading the page?

Comment: I should just stop posting questions here and actually read my web development book -_- Thanks Samitha :D

Comment: ohh Dave.Nice.if you need a help we are here

Comment: "another query takes place" - this is unlikely to be the best scenario